# Projection of TRMM in dictionary

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, summarizing, trmm

I am trying to extract the 24 hour precipitation data of a given polygon by creating a dictionary . I have gotten results but i'm not sure if the parameters I have inserted in the reducer are correct.

The resolution that is given on GEE dataset for TRMM is 0.25 arc, so I believe it is not in WGS84, so i'm not sure if I should put 0.25 or to calculte it in km.
As both give me numbers, I don't know which one is correct

```
var meanDictionary =totalRain.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 0.25,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
```

Then, I have used the reducer sum() but i'm not sure if it will give me the sum of all the pixels I have on th eone image or for each pixel it will give me the sum of all the 8 umages I have used.

To better understand my cocnerns, I recommend to see my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/39edb9298606d1912331e5d7f7d7723a

the polygon I have used is located in north of Thailand, and is random, so any polygon there would work

Answer (score 2):

"scale" in reduceRegion() is, according to the docs:

> "A nominal scale in meters of the projection to work in."

So setting this to 0.25 is not what you want to do. Instead, you can use "crs":

> The projection to work in. If unspecified, the projection of the
>   image's first band is used. If specified in addition to scale,
>   rescaled to the specified scale.

Either don't specify the crs or scale at all, and use the default (first band's projection), or manually set it:

```
var projectionTRMM = dataset.first().projection()
var meanDictionary =totalRain.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: projectionTRMM,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b36cc12804b0c963f91bf4745d82daed

Comment: I still get error: Dictionary (Error)
Image.reduceRegion: You must specify a scale or crsTransform when specifying a crs.

Comment: it is the same I have post here, but with your suggestion of CRS

Comment: try this now, I thinlk I have shared  the geometry https://code.earthengine.google.com/14e04e193981f9c69e0a4305eedc397a

Comment: ther should be another polygon there, doyou see it?

Comment: Try this: 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e46d84374733dabbd9c72e0b58f04d57